# Django atomic transaction handle unique constraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have model

```
class Order(models.Model):
  order_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', unique = True)
  amount = models.FloatField()
```

And I have this cycle which saves objects to my database from json and validates for unique field `order_id`

```
for json_obj in json_data:
   order = Order(symbol=json_obj['order_id'], amount= json_obj['amnount'])
   try:
     order.save()
   except IntegrityError as exception:
     if 'UNIQUE constraint failed' in exception.args[0]:
        print('duplicate order id => skip this')
        continue
```

Everything works fine, but when I add  @transaction.atomic decorator to my function everything breaks.
And I get an error:

```
 "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
    django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

What is recommended way of handling such case?

> UPD: I use transaction atomic decorator to speed up my code, cause I
> have big list of orders to save and it is quite a costly operation
> which runs in background.
>
> UPD2: I tried to use `get_or_create method`  but didn't get any real
> boost of performance with it, so can't use it

Comment: Why would you add a ***`transaction.atomic`*** decorator ? What advantage you'd expect by adding it into the code, ***in this particular case***?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have many order objects, so when I use transaction.atomic my code runs a lot faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) :

> The correct way to catch database errors is around an atomic block

Here a an adaptation of your code :

```py
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction

for json_obj in json_data:
    order = Order(symbol=json_obj['order_id'], amount=json_obj['amnount'])
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            order.save()
    except IntegrityError as exception:
        if 'UNIQUE constraint failed' in exception.args[0]:
            print('duplicate order id => skip this')
            continue
```

You can also use `get_or_create` to achieve what you want :

```py
for json_obj in json_data:
    obj, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        symbol=json_obj['order_id'],
        defaults={'amount': json_obj['amnount'])},
    )
    if not created:
        print('order id already existing => skip this')
```

If you want a fast code (as per your comment), you can use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

```py
orders_to_create = []

for json_obj in json_data:
    orders_to_create.append(Order(symbol=json_obj['order_id'], amount=json_obj['amnount']))

Order.objects.bulk_create(orders_to_create, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

Please do note that

> On databases that support it (all but Oracle), setting the ignore_conflicts parameter to True tells the database to ignore failure to insert any rows that fail constraints such as duplicate unique values

Without using the `ignore_conflicts` settings, you can do :

```py
orders_to_create = []

order_ids = [json_obj['order_id'] for json_obj in json_data]

existing_order_ids = Order.objects.filter(symbol__in=order_ids).values_list('symbol', flat=True)

for json_obj in json_data:
    # this condition prevents any IntegrityError du to an existing order_id
    if json_obj['order_id'] not in existing_order_ids:
        orders_to_create.append(Order(symbol=json_obj['order_id'], amount=json_obj['amnount']))

Order.objects.bulk_create(orders_to_create)
```

Comment: I tried first and second option as you suggested, unfotunately, my code didn't speed up using this solutions..

Comment: @user2950593 speed was not one of your requirements, but does this solves the problem you mentioned in your question (break of code) ?

Comment: @user2950593 I have added another block of code which might speed up your code.

Comment: if I write ignore_conflicts=True will it  violate unique constraint requirement or will it just skip such orders? (will try this in a moment)

Comment: Ignore = True: Enabling this parameter disables setting the primary key on each model instance (if the database normally supports it). (C) - that sounds quite alarming

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have edited my answer without this settings that can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220299/discussion-between-charlesthk-and-user2950593).

Answer (score 1):

first, the `transaction.atomic` decorator postpones the database commit to the end of your decorated function. Therefore your exception handling now will not work, because the exception gets thrown outside of your try-except block.
The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) also advise you to not catch exceptions inside the atomic block.

Perhaps this could also causing you the trouble of a `TransactionManagementError`. If an exception occurs inside an atomic block you are not allowed to do any database queries.

You should move the try-except outside of your function and check, if this solves your issue.

Comment: As far as I understand if I move try except outside my function It will not save anything to database in case of error, but I want to save unique records